# Restrict folder access in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I want nobody to access my private folder, I'd like to set a password for it or just make it only accessible by `root` user.

How can I get it? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: I've summed up some essentials about users and privileges in this answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102911/how-to-set-root-permission-for-all-users/102917#102917 - this might give you some more grip on this topic named "**MODES**" -> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the owner or root, execute the command

```
# chmod -R 700 /path/to/folder
```

The `chmod` command changes the permissions of the file/folder. The `700` means that the owner has full access, and no one else. The `-R` means to apply the rules recursively (through subfolders). You will also want to run a `chown`

```
# chown user:user -R /path/to/folder
```

The `chown` command changes the owner of the file/folder. The `user:` part is the username to apply the owner as; the `:user` part is for the group. Every user typically has it's own group as well. Again, the `-R` is to recurse through to subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Canadian Luke's answer:

It is actually not required to set the entire contents (recursively) of a folder to `chmod -R 700`.

In order to access a **directory or any child content**, you need `+x` permissions for your user. If you remove that the user can not access any of the child contents of this folder, no matter what the permission of the contents are.

In the above case, the command below would be enough:

```
# chown user:group /path/to/folder
# chmod go-x /path/to/folder
```

That way you can restrict access without changing the permissions or ownership inside your folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at [encfs](http://www.arg0.net/encfsintro). It's easy to set up and use, and will encrypt a directory using the password of your choice. On ubuntu, it's available via apt as the `encfs` package. Setting up a new encfs volume is as easy as

```
$ encfs ~/.priv ~/priv
```

where `~/.priv` will be the encrypred version. See the link in this post for a more detailed intro to the tool.